# Save changes in an Excel spreadsheet that were made using MS Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In my database, I have a VBA script that opens an Excel spreadsheet and removes the first row so the new first row is the header row.

When I save the file in Access VBA and open the file in Excel, nothing is there.

If I reimport the spreadsheet, the data is visible.

I changed my script around and if I don't save the changes the file is ok. If I  save the changes then this problem appears.

```
dim sheetpath as string
dim xl as excel.application
dim xlbook as excel.workbook
dim xlsheet as excel.worksheet

sheetpath = "c:\users\me\export.xlsx"

set xl = createobject("Excel.Application")
set xlbook = GetObject(sheetpath)

xl.visible = true
set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)

If xlsheet.Range("a1").mergecells = true then
    xlsheet.cells.unmerge
end if

if xlsheet.range("a1") = "Values" then
    xlsheet.rows(1).delete
end if

xlbook.close savechanges:=true
xl.application.qit
set xl = nothing
set xlbook = nothing
set xlsheet = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a reboot.

But before you do that, check in Task Manager / Process Explorer, if you have multiple Excel processes still running.

Instead of

```
set xl = createobject("Excel.Application")
set xlbook = GetObject(sheetpath)
```

do

```
Set xlbook = GetObject(sheetpath)
Set xl = xlbook.Application
```

What's this?

```
xl.application.qit
```

It should be

```
xl.Quit
```

And clear your references in the correct order, from bottom to top:

```
set xlsheet = nothing
set xlbook = nothing
set xl = nothing
```

Comment: Still didn't work.  I checked task manager and rebooted as well as applied the settings you suggested.

Comment: Also, I decided to open the VBA editor in Excel with the file open.  It sees the correct Tab in the VBA editor of the sheet.  Let me also reiterate, this was working fine yesterday.